# Multi functional email set up with Code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I have an application built in CodeIgniter. I needed some help with the following  email related tasks. Please note all emails will require SSL.

1) Send email to congratulate and welcome the user to the site
2) Send an email to confirm a user account has been deleted should they choose to leave.
3) Send an email to alert the user for a request sent to them from another user. 
4) Set up and send an email for "forgot username" and last but not not least
5) Send an email to reset password in case the user can't remember how to login.

Thanks for your help, appreciate it.

function signup(){

```
$data = array(
'sign_up_mail'=>'Welcome and thanks for joining...'
);

$htmlMessage =  $this->parser->parse('user/email/signup_html', $data, true);
$txtMessage = $this->parser->parse('user/email/signup_txt',  $data, true);

#send the message
$this->email->from('test@gmail.com', 'test app');
$this->email->to($this->input->post('email_address'));
$this->email->subject('Account Registration');
$this->email->message($htmlMessage);
$this->email->alt_message($txtMessage);
$this->email->send();
```

}

Would you use this listed below as the method for changing the message within the various emails?
data['message'] = "Hey there, you've got a follower request!";
$email = $this->load->view('email/template', $data, TRUE);

I presume this method works for simple things like user welcome and alerts etc. How would I go about connecting a process to resetting a username/password or confirming a deletion? How do you connect the email process with manipulating data in the db?

Comment: "Some help", or "some code"?

Comment: I pasted some of the applied code, if you are under the impression that there are shady intentions present please ignore the request.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I think you are looking for some kind of authentication related tasks. If so, there is an authentication, library in codeigniter, that provides complete authentication system. Have a look, it it is useful to you. http://konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/